# Module resolution exeption with odfdom and Gradle

Tags: java, odfdom

I am modulirizing and existing non modular application. To make my life easier with the Java modules system, I decided to pick up a working example https://github.com/beryx-gist/badass-jlink-example-log4j2-javafx which is similar to my app and add the depencies I will need to that and make it work. I started with `odfdom`, a I am processing lot of OpenDocument spreadsheets using `jOpenDocument`, but `odfdom` looks now more promising so I am moving to that. I get the following error when running the example:

```
java.lang.module.ResolutionException: Modules maven.core and maven.artifact export package org.apache.maven.artifact.repository to module org.json
```

This occurs when I add the following line to the `buid.gradle`:

```
implementation 'org.odftoolkit:odfdom-java:0.10.0'
```

otherwise the project builds and runs as expected.
How I am supposed to solve this issue?
Here is the `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
    id 'org.javamodularity.moduleplugin' version '1.8.9'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.10'
    id 'org.beryx.jlink' version "2.24.1"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = "11"
targetCompatibility = "11"

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.11.1' //automatic-module
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.1' //module
    implementation 'org.odftoolkit:odfdom-java:0.10.0' //none
}

javafx {
    version = 16
    modules = ['javafx.controls']
}

application {
    mainClass = "org.openjfx.HelloFX"
    mainModule = "hellofx"
}
```

and the `module-info.java`:

```
module hellofx {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires org.apache.logging.log4j;
    
    exports org.openjfx;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may need to add to module-info.java the module name for implementation 'org.odftoolkit:odfdom-java:0.10.0':

```
requires odfdom.java;
```

I am not getting your error but getting lots of other module errors eg

```
 .... module reads package org.apache.maven.settings from both maven.settings and maven.core
```

Solution for me was to add some excludes in my build.gradle in order to get it to compile:

```
     configurations {
         compileOnly.exclude group: 'xerces', module: 'xercesImpl'       
         // exclude from compile but allow at run time  
     }
     

     implementation (group: 'org.odftoolkit', name: 'odfdom-java', version: '0.10.0') {         
        exclude group: 'org.apache.maven', module: 'maven-core'
        exclude group: 'org.apache.maven', module: 'maven-plugin-api'
        exclude group: 'io.github.git-commit-id', module: 'git-commit-id-plugin-core'
     }
```

My build.gradle is more complex that yours and I seemed to get a lot of module clashes and so it's not the same issue, but I hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks David for your reply, little bit late... I changed lot of things in the project and stopped working on it for a while, so was not totally sure of what solved. I accepted your answer because probably it was what you suggested: adding requires odfdom.java